# How to display complex objects in multipart/form-data requests in Swagger UI?

Tags: multipartform-data, swagger-ui, openapi

I am using OpenAPI 3.0.1 and I am trying to send a request as `multipart/form-data`. The request body is defined as follows:

```yaml
       requestBody:
         content:
           multipart/form-data: # Media type
             schema:            # Request payload
               type: object
               properties:      # Request parts
                 media:            # Part 1 (string value)
                   type: string
                 address:       # Part2 (object)
                   type: object
                   properties:
                     street:
                       type: string
                     city:
                       type: string
                 profileImage:  # Part 3 (an image)
                   type: string
                   format: binary
```

Here, the `address` field is an object. Swagger UI shows the `address` field itself, but does not show its properties `street`, `city`. Why is that?

[image: Multipart form fields in Swagger UI]

Answer (score 0):

[This issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/7268) was fixed in Swagger UI v. 3.51.0. Make sure you're using the latest version.